# Display React Native Redux Saga API response

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I have been studying/working with [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) for a couple weeks now, and I'm trying to get a grasp on working with [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [Redux-Sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/). I have tried researching this for several days now and (thought) I was getting the hang of it, but unfortunately I am still struggling. Here are some resources I have read and attempted:

https://shift.infinite.red/using-redux-saga-to-simplify-your-growing-react-native-codebase-2b8036f650de

https://hackernoon.com/moving-api-requests-to-redux-saga-21780f49cbc8

I am using the [Ignite-CLI](https://infinite.red/ignite) boilerplate to create an app that queries an API for weather data. The API request works when using the regular `api.get()` function from `apisauce` but I can't get the Redux Saga actions to return the data. I'm thinking I just don't understand the concept well enough.

Here is my `Api.js` file that uses `apisauce` to fetch the JSON data from the given parameters (this works perfectly)

**/App/Services/Api.js**

```
// a library to wrap and simplify api calls
import apisauce from 'apisauce'

// our "constructor"
const create = (baseURL = 'https://my-api-url.com/api/') => {

  const apiId = 'xxxxxxx'
  const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  const resortKey = 'xxxxxx'
  const apiParams = resortKey + '?app_id=' + apiId + '&app_key=' + apiKey

  const api = apisauce.create({
    // base URL is read from the "constructor"
    baseURL,
    // here are some default headers
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    // 10 second timeout...
    timeout: 10000
  })

  const getReport = () => api.get(apiParams)

  return {
    getReport,
  }
}

// let's return back our create method as the default.
export default {
  create
}
```

Ignite CLI has an awesome generator that generates redux actions and sagas automatically. Here are those generated files:

**/App/Redux/SnowReportRedux.js** (Redux Actions)

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  snowReportRequest: ['data'],
  snowReportSuccess: ['payload'],
  snowReportFailure: null
})

export const SnowReportTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  data: null,
  fetching: null,
  payload: null,
  error: null
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */

// request the data from an api
export const request = (state, { data }) =>
  state.merge({ fetching: true, data, payload: null })

// successful api lookup
export const success = (state, action) => {
  const { payload } = action
  return state.merge({ fetching: false, error: null, payload })
}

// Something went wrong somewhere.
export const failure = state =>
  state.merge({ fetching: false, error: true, payload: null })

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.SNOW_REPORT_REQUEST]: request,
  [Types.SNOW_REPORT_SUCCESS]: success,
  [Types.SNOW_REPORT_FAILURE]: failure
})
```

**/App/Sagas/SnowReportSagas.js**

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import SnowReportActions from '../Redux/SnowReportRedux'

export function * getSnowReport (api, action) {
  const { data } = action
  // make the call to the api
  const response = yield call(api.getReport, data)

  // success?
  if (response.ok) {
    yield put(SnowReportActions.snowReportSuccess(response.data))
  } else {
    yield put(SnowReportActions.snowReportFailure())
  }
}
```

Then, following the example they provided, I added the `SnowReportActions` from `SnowReportRedux.js` and the `getSnowReport` function from `SnowReportSagas.js` to the root saga function as such:

```
//...imports & constants

export default function * root () {
  yield all([
    // some sagas only receive an action
    takeLatest(StartupTypes.STARTUP, startup),

    // some sagas receive extra parameters in addition to an action
    takeLatest(SnowReportTypes.SNOW_REPORT_REQUEST, getSnowReport, api)
  ])
}
```

Now here is where I get confused; How do I actually call those dispatch actions within my components or screens? I understand I have to `import SnowReport Actions from '../Redux/SnowReportRedux` and `mapDispatchToProps` but I can't get the dispatch to fire... Here are some pieces from one of my screens:

**/App/Containers/ResortReportScreen.js**

```
//.. constructor

componentDidMount () {
  this.props.getSnowReport();
}

// .. render() / close component

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getSnowReport: () => dispatch({ type: SnowReportActions.snowReportRequest() })
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ResortReportScreen)
```

When the `componentDidMount ()` function fires it should `dispatch` the `SnowReportActions.snowReportRequest()` action, right? Whenever I use `console.log()` to return the response of that action it doesn't end up firing. What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the data from my API request to display when using `actions`?

My `sagaMiddleware` and `reducers` are all generated automatically by Ignite. If it is necessary to show those just ask.

Comment: Checkout my repo [here](https://github.com/pritishvaidya/create-react-native-redux-app) with a sample example.

Answer (score 0):

The function `SnowReportActions.snowReportRequest()` is an action creator which return an action you have to dispatch. You can fix your code like that :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getSnowReport: () => dispatch(SnowReportActions.snowReportRequest())
  }
}
```

You can even simplify your code using an object instead of a method for `mapDispatchToProps` (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getSnowReport: SnowReportActions.snowReportRequest
}
```